# django-rest-framework and http to https redirect

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, https, django-rest-framework

I want to redirect all http requests to https in my django app. The app has also an api through which I make request to database. Those requests are made through http protocol and I want to redirect them to https  as well . Below configuration works well with requests made in web browser (http are correctly redirected to https and the website displays). However, the requests through api cause 301 error (Moved Permanently). Am I missing something here? This is my nginx configuration:

```
 server {
               listen         80;
               server_name    myurl.com;
               return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
 }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name myurl.com;

        ssl_certificate /path_to_cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /path_to_key; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;       
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
        #proxy_buffering off;
    }
```

Django settings:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Comment: 301 is not an error, 301 is a redirect. This status code is used for permanent URL redirection. You have it setup in your server configuration.

Comment: good point!  So how should i setup my server to follow that redirect after api request?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot redirect POST request with 301. It will be changed to GET. See [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.2). You can try changing status code to 307 Temporary Redirect. 307 does not change method on redirect.